# How to put form data to another website

Tags: php, forms, post, dreamweaver, email

HI !,
I have a website on my local network.
All those who use the network have their corrosponding GMAIL accounts.
The site is kinda portal for all of us.

I want them to be able to fill up their Username and Password on my homepage and get loggeed into Gmail; i.e post my form data in mail.google.com's form that accepts Username and Password.

Please help me out.

Comment: In the very **very** best case, you will be training users to provide third parties with their credentials for other sites. **Don't do that**. Just link to GMail and let people use Google's forms.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at OpenID: it's a way of authenticating users against an already known service. [GMail implements OpenID](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thx Buddy ! i wl surely giv it a try.